# How to use Seriously.js difference blend effect on successive video stream frames

Tags: javascript, video-processing

I'm using Appcelerator and wanted to do some video processing.  I came across Seriously.js and saw that you could potentially do some impressive image and video stream manipulation in a "node" pipeline.  So before taking on the appcelerator part of this effort, I figured I'd coerce the camera-source example (see: http://brianchirls.github.io/Seriously.js/examples) into doing more than just edge detection.  So I quickly added a pixelation effect on top of that.  Code looked like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Seriously.js Camera Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="target" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

<script src="../../seriously.js"></script>
<script src="../../sources/seriously.camera.js"></script>
<script src="../../effects/seriously.edge.js"></script>
<script src="../../effects/seriously.pixelate.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
//main code goes here

// declare our variables
var seriously, // the main object that holds the entire composition
source, // wrapper object for source video
edge, // edge detection effect
pixelate, // pixelate effect
target; // a wrapper object for our target canvas

if (Seriously.incompatible('camera')) {
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Sorry, your browser does not support getUserMedia'));
document.querySelector('canvas').style.display = 'none';
return;
}

// construct our seriously object
seriously = new Seriously();

// time to get serious
source = seriously.source('camera');
target = seriously.target('#target');
edge = seriously.effect('edge');
pixelate = seriously.effect('pixelate');

// connect all our nodes in the right order
edge.source = source;
pixelate.source = edge;
target.source = pixelate;

seriously.go();
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And cool it worked.  But what I really wanted to do is use the blend effect (specifically difference).  This takes a top and bottom for two different sources (images or videos, I assume) and performs the specified blend operation between corresponding frames.  But what I really want is to have one video stream operated on and have the difference blend effect performed between frames.  The closest I could get, which really isn't very close is to use the same video stream as both the top source and bottom source.  Of course, there's no difference between them, so I don't really get what I'm after.  So I'm guessing I need to access the previous frame, but I don't know how given the operation I see in the API.  Here's the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Seriously.js Camera Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="target" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

<script src="../../seriously.js"></script>
<script src="../../sources/seriously.camera.js"></script>
<script src="../../effects/seriously.edge.js"></script>
<script src="../../effects/seriously.blend.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
//main code goes here

// declare our variables
var seriously, // the main object that holds the entire composition
source, // wrapper object for source video
edge, // edge detection effect
difference, // difference effect
target; // a wrapper object for our target canvas

if (Seriously.incompatible('camera')) {
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Sorry, your browser does not support getUserMedia'));
document.querySelector('canvas').style.display = 'none';
return;
}

// construct our seriously object
seriously = new Seriously();

// time to get serious
source = seriously.source('camera');
target = seriously.target('#target');
edge = seriously.effect('edge');
difference = seriously.effect('blend', { mode: "difference" } );

// connect all our nodes in the right order
edge.source = source;
difference.top = edge;
difference.bottom = edge; // I really want a frame sooner or later from edge
target.source = difference;

seriously.go();
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I look forward to a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously.js doesn't do much in the way of manipulating image frames in time, at least not in the core code, since it's designed for processing live video, and storing frames could potentially take up a lot of memory.

However, there is a "freeze" effect plugin that could help. A freeze node has a "frozen" setting that causes it to stop updating, and you can use it to process an older frame. What you'd do is set up two freeze nodes, each taking input from your camera, and alternate which of the two nodes is frozen every time you render a frame. You'd also alternate the inputs of your blend node so the "bottom" input always receives the old frame (the "frozen" node) and the top receives the current frame (the unfrozen node).

It's best to set the bottom and top inputs on the blend node to "select" nodes, which will allow you to swap between the two different freeze nodes without disconnecting and re-connecting nodes on your node graph. This way you avoid any costly operations that sometimes happen when you change the network around. And you can do the swap in a callback to the ".go()" method, which runs before every frame render.

Here's a link to a working example:
https://jsbin.com/hisuha/edit?js

I didn't use an edge filter here because it didn't seem necessary, though you're welcome to give it a shot. I'd try putting it right after the camera node and have both freeze nodes use your edge node as the input. It's also worth noting that this is not quite the same as an [optical flow effect](https://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js/issues/97), which I'm working on.